# Adding a node to a position of Doubly Linked List

Tags: python, algorithm, list, linked-list

I'm trying to implement a Doubly Linked List but, when i try to add a node between at given position the list going an infinite loop (i'm checking with a print method to is it correct or not ), i has the problem at python, i use same idea to java there were no problem.

Java code like that

```
 public void addBetween(int pos,Dnode node){
    Dnode temp =this.head;
    for (int i = 0; i <pos ; i++) {
        temp =temp.next;
    }
    node.next =temp.next;
    temp.next =node;
    node.prev =temp;
    if (node.next != null) {
        node.next.prev =node;
    }
    size++;
}
```

(consider there are two node between given position)

Python code is:

```
def insertbetween(self, node: Dnode, index: int):
    n1 = self.head
    for x in range(index):
        n1 = n1.next
    node.next = n1.next
    if node.next != None:
        node.next.prev = node
    n1.next = node
    node.prev = n1
```

What can be the problem with the python code ?

Comment: You're not doing the `.prev` and `.next` setting in the same order, which is part of the problem. Make sure you keep in mind what `node` and `n1` are *on every line*.

Comment: Should it be `range(index)` not `range(i)` ?

Comment: There is nothing in your code that can explain an *infinite* loop. Can you provide also the code with which you trigger that method and get into an infinite loop, ... so we can reproduce it?

Comment: i'm trying to print the list with this method                                                                            `def printList(self):
        tmp =self.head
        while tmp is not None:
            print(tmp.data,end =" ")
            tmp =tmp.next`